# how can i get mean of values of entire column for pandas dataframe using index of the column

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I need to get the mean for the entire column by accessing the column by its index

pd.mean(axis=1) gives me mean for each row of the column. But i need the mean for the sum of all the values in column similar to describe function for pandas dataframe.

Date       michael burleigh

2/7/2016   0

2/14/2016  0

2/21/2016  0

2/28/2016  0

3/6/2016   0

3/13/2016  0

3/20/2016  0

3/27/2016  0

4/3/2016   98

4/10/2016  99

4/17/2016  99

4/24/2016  100

5/1/2016   100

5/8/2016    0

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}]
df = pandas.DataFrame.frompandas.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-01-03', freq='D')
df.apply(np.mean)

# Answer
# a    1.000000
# b    3.333333
# c    4.333333
# dtype: float64
```

Also if you know the column name, you could just do.

```
In [13]: df ['b'].mean()
Out[13]: 3.3333333333333335
```